# @BeforeStep and @AfterStep not working in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

`@BeforeStep` and `@AfterStep` annotations are not working in spring batch. When I run the job, before and after step methods are not being executed. I see other people also had same issue with respective the proxy, but I am not sure what exactly does that mean in this context. I have added below my batch configuration class, let me know if I am missing something.

PFB my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution){
        log.info("Before step");
       
    }
    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution){
       log.info("After step");
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Entity> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['sampleDate']}") String sampleDate, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {


        log.info("ItemReader iteration");
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Entity> Entity = new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Entity>()
                .name("sampleReader").dataSource(dataSource)
                .sql("select * from sample_table")
                .rowMapper(new CustomRowMapper()).build();

        return Entity;

    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("sampleJob")
                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                                .start(step())
                                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {


        return stepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep").<Entity, Entity>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader(null,null))
                .writer(writer(null))
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Entity> writer(DataSource datasource){

        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Entity>()
                .dataSource(datasource)
                .sql("insert into sample_table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (:col1,:col2,:col3")
                .beanMapped()
                .build();
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And they should becuase? They aren't registered as part of the Job nor Step, so no they won't be executed. You will need to add the configuration class as a listener to the steps ou want this to apply to .

Comment: Yes after adding listener they are working..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This started working after I have added listener class and configured it in the step

```
public class StepResultListener implements StepExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(final org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution stepExecution) {
        log.info("Before Step Start Time{}", Instant.now());
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(final org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution stepExecution) {
        log.info("After Step End Time{}", Instant.now());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And update the step to

```
    @Bean
    public Step step() throws Exception {


        return stepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep").<Entity, Entity>chunk(1000)
                .reader(reader(null,null))
                .writer(writer(null))
                .listener(new StepResultListener())
                .build();

    }
```

Comment: The annotations will work as well, but you have to call `listener` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have another question…When we define chunk size as 100…So does item reader make 100 database calls to form a chunk or is it a single call with limit 100? I am confused how Item reader works

Comment: That depends on the item reader being used. Generally 1 call which iterates until the chunk size or the end has been reached.